# Which modifier to choose when they belong to the same class?

Tags: grammar, adjectives

In my book I'm asked to write a sentence using the following words :

> Taipei is a / lively / city / with huge skyscrapers / modern.

According to my book, which is named *Passage* and published by Cambridge, the order of modifiers is like so:

> Quality, size, age, type, name and descriptive phrase. Since Shape, color and material can also describe a noun, the order of modifiers can also be like this:
>
> Quality, size, shape, age, color, type, material and noun.

Now, I can write my sentence in two ways but unsure which is right or if both are correct.

1. "Taipei is a **lively modern** city with huge skyscrapers."

OR

2. "Taipei is a **modern lively** city with huge skyscrapers."

Both words *modern* and *lively* are qualities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**modern lively city** would suggest that there have been lively cities throughout history, and Tapei is a modern example of one.

**lively modern city** would suggest that the city of Tapei is both lively and modern.

**modern** is a kind of *age* (compare its opposite, **ancient**) and would come after *quality*, **lively**.

Comment: Wow! Didn't know that modern is a word about age.

Comment: A modern city is one whose buildings and infrastructure are (for the most part) *new, not old*. You understand **new** and **old** as words about age, right?  Other "age-related" terms might be "19th century", "jurassic", "antediluvian".  Age references aren't necessarily numbers expressing years.

Comment: If you use a corma then there's really no ambiguity.

Comment: True, a longer-than-normal pause between the adjectives and a concomitant adjustment of the intonation (represented in writing with a comma) can signal that the adjectives are to be given equal weight as attributes of the noun.

Answer (score 6):

Either

> Taipei is a lively modern city with huge skyscrapers.

or

> Taipei is a modern lively  city with huge skyscrapers.

is technically correct.

I would probably prefer the first one. This is because *modern city* is modified by *lively*, telling what kind of *modern city* it is.

Whereas, in the second one Taipei  is a *lively city* with *modern* saying what kind of *lively city* it is.

Since *modern* is probably more important or fundamental  than *lively*, the first combination is better.

Think of the word *lovely*. We would also say it is a *lovely modern city* (telling what kind of *modern city* it is, and probably not the other way around).

As Mark Hubbard has hinted, you would probably want to use a comma to separate the two adjectives in any of the phrases  using *modern* and *lively* (or *lovely*).